# How to convert Word track changes markup to document content?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2003

I would like to edit a Word document with Track Changes on, and then save the document with the track changes markup as the actual document. For instance, deleted words should be in the final document with strike-through. In addition, I would like to keep the formatting from Advanced Track Changes Options.

Comment: Unfortunately, the output needs to be a Word 2003 file (.doc) for the next person in the workflow. The answer would preferably work in Word 2003.

Comment: I would take a guess that a macro would be the only way to turn markup into actual document content. Perhaps try down that road and see how hard it would be and if it's worth it.

Comment: I, too, would find this very useful (now in a much later version of word).

Answer (score -1):

I am using Word 2010, so I am not sure how the menus are in Word 2003, I think it's `Tools > Options > Tracked Changes`. What you are looking to do is set it to `Show all revisions inline` which will show changes within the text rather than in balloons at the side or bottom. It should look like this;

[image]

Comment: The problem is not where the changes are presented, but rather how to have all the markup in a final document. A solution could be tested by  subsequently selecting Accepting All Changes, and the track changes markup from before the solution was applied would still remain.

Comment: So you are trying to figure out how to `Accept Changes` and keep the markup within the text? In the past I have just not accepted the changes so the markup is not removed.

Comment: What I am looking for would be more like `Accept Markup`. Not accepting changes is the status quo, and not a workable solution. One particular benefit I am looking for is for there to be no Changed Lines indicator. I can achieve this on my computer through the Advanced Track Changes Options. However, the next person in the workflow will see changes marked up however their Word is configured. For my needs, these variations are untenable.

Comment: @Patrick This is an old thread but I imagine "Simple Markup" does what you want(ed).